# Use a sub-domain of an already used domain in Azure AD for an Azure AD B2C tenant

Tags: azure, subdomain, azure-ad-b2c

I'm facing an issue for quite some time now regarding an Azure AD B2C tenant.

The thing is I already have an Azure AD working for employees authentication (Office 365) and I need to create a B2C tenant to authenticate our customers.

My main domain names are already registered in my main Azure AD subscription (for mail purposes) and I want to use a sub-domain of one of them for the B2C tenant (like `b2c.mydomain.com`) which actually seems not possible.

Whenever I try to do it, the verification process seems to never end ...

[image: Verification process]

[image: TXT record]

Help or just "I confirm this is not possible" would be much appreciated :)

Edit : I just added images of the verification process and the TXT record I added in the DNS zone, but seems weird to me to put @ in the name for a sub-domain which would be b2c.

Edit 2 : result of the verification process
[image: Result]

Comment: According to this, adding a sub-domain to another tenant should be possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/domains-manage#add-subdomains-of-a-custom-domain

Comment: Thank you for your comment juunas, I edited my post adding some images and comments. Like you said, It should be possible according to the link you provided but I can't figure out why it is not working for me until now ...

Comment: Have you tried putting b2c instead of @ in the DNS record?

Comment: yes I already tried if I remember correctly. But I will add a second record with the b2c name just to be sure.

Comment: @juunas I added the result of the verification process which shows it failed

Answer (score 1):

It's supported. Avoid using @, some DNS providers support it, others the * character and others are good just with a blank entry. You just have to add the records in the mydomain.com DNS zone.

**MX**
Name: b2c.mydomain.com
Proritity: {priority}
TTL: 3600 or 7200 works fine too

**TXT**
Name: b2c.mydomain.com
Destination or Value: {ms=xxxxxx}

Edit 2 error image is clear bout the domain name already configured. Maybe you missed the b2c prefix/part?